# angular and rxjs - removing properties from object

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an endpoint that returns the following object properties:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "department": "sample",
  "address": "sample",
  "email": "sample@email.com",
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "100",
      "product_type": "A",
      "product_category": "sample",
      "category": "sample"
    },
    {
      "id": "101",
      "product_type": "A",
      "product_category": "sample",
      "category": "sample"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm doing like this on Angular

```
this.httpService.get<Product>(<my_endpoint>).pipe(map(response => response.data))
```

I need to remove all the properties product_type from the array of objects and keep the rest intact. I can't find if is possible to do this with only RxJs library filtering capabilities.

Comment: You could try to use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score -1):

Inside your map function do this:

```
map((response) =>{ 
let data = response.data;
let products = data.products;

products =products.map((product) =>{ 
delete product['property1'];
return product; // without deleted properties;
}) 
data.products =products ;
return data;
})
```

Comment: I need to remove only the object properties inside the array

Comment: map pure function will transform each object in your array. just copy this code then inside map function use the key You want to remove . I used property1 property2 ... as placeholders to guide how to apply change.

Comment: I have edited code it from mobile.

Answer (score -1):

You can use RxJS `pluck` and `map`, as well as array map and object destructuring to remove the un-needed property.

```js
this.httpService.get<Product>(<my_endpoint>).pipe(
   pluck('data'),
   map( data => {
     const products = data.products.map( p => {
       const {product_type, ...others} = p;
       return {
          ...others
       }
     });
     return {
       ...data,
       products
     }
   })
)
```

Note: don't use `delete` on objects if you can avoid it (it mutates the object)